# How to evaluate / approximate polynomial sum expression over integers?

Tags: calculus, integration, polynomials, summation, approximation

Given
$$P(x) = \sum_{k=0}^Nc_kx^k$$

Can we derive some exact formula for

$$\sum_{k=0}^N P(k)$$

The only thing I can think of is the integral approximation:

$$\int_{0}^{N} P(x)dx \approx \sum_{k=0}^N P(k)$$

or maybe broken into smaller pieces

$$\int_{k}^{k+1} P(x)dx \approx \frac{P(k)+P(k+1)} 2$$
Maybe there are better approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are looking for a "nice" form to express
$$
\sum\limits_{j = 0}^n {P(j)}  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {c_{\,k} \sum\limits_{l = 0}^n {l^{\,k} } } 
$$

Now, as far as I know, the different formulations for the sums of powers can be summarized in
$$
\eqalign{
  & S_m (n + 1) = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,l\, \le \,n} {l^{\,k} } \quad \left| {\;0 \le {\rm integer }k,n} \right. =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,j\,\left( { \le \,k} \right)} {\left\langle \matrix{
  k \cr 
  j \cr}  \right\rangle \left( \matrix{
  n + 1 + j \cr 
  k + 1 \cr}  \right)}  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,j\,\left( { \le \,k} \right)} {\;j!\;\left\{ \matrix{
  k \cr 
  j \cr}  \right\}\left( \matrix{
  n + 1 \cr 
  j + 1 \cr}  \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over {k + 1}}\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,j\, \le \,m} {\left( \matrix{
  k + 1 \cr 
  j \cr}  \right)\;B(j)\;\left( {n + 1} \right)^{\,k + 1 - j} }  \cr} 
$$
where:
 - the angle brackets denote the [Eulerian Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_number);
 - the curly brackets denote the [Stirling Numbers of 2nd kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind);
 - $B(j)$ denote the [Bernoulli Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number).

Therefore, you cannot find a close form in general, unless the $c_k$ obey to a particular  function of the index.

Comment: Thank you, I am not so familiar with these numbers, but I will check them out.

Comment: Glad to help: those numbers  are in any case much interesting.

Answer (score 0):

$$ h \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} P(kh) > \int_{0}^{1} P(x)dx > h\sum_{k=1}^N P(kh)$$

where $h=1/N$.

As N becomes larger, the magnitude of difference of the terms in the inequality decreases.

Comment: Not so sure how it helps. But I will look more at it later.